# Firebase Cloud Messaging, notifications summary and custom builders when the app is closed?

Tags: android, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

If when the app is in the foreground I provide this custom builders for notifications, how to I get the same result when the app is closed or in the background? Is it even possible?
I know you can specify to collapse notifications but what about group summary and all other functions of these builders? like specifying styles etc? It sounds dumb that this only works for the application on the foreground.

```
var summary = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ApplicationContext, channelId)
        .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().SetSummaryText("This is the summary text"))
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.small_icon)
        .SetGroup(groupId)
        .SetGroupSummary(true)
        .SetPriority((Int32)NotificationPriority.High)
        .SetDefaults((Int32)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (Int32)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
        .SetContentIntent(activity)
        .Build();
    var localNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ApplicationContext, channelId)
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.small_icon)
        .SetContentTitle(pushNotification.Title)
        .SetContentText(pushNotification.Body)
        .SetGroup(groupId)
        .SetPriority((Int32)NotificationPriority.High)
        .SetDefaults((Int32)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (Int32)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
        .SetAutoCancel(autoCancel: true)
        .SetContentIntent(activity)
        .Build();
```

So after more tries what i found was:

- if i do not set the "notification" property on the server, the onMessageReceived is called with the app on the foreground and background. If the app is closed no notification is received tho.
- if i set the "notification" property on the server. the onMessageReceived is called only with the app on the foreground, but background and app closed they do not get grouped because no custom builder is called.

Comment: Will the function `OnMessageReceived` of your firebase app be triggered when your app is on background or closed status? For more about FCM notifications, check [FCM notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows#implement-firebasemessagingservice).

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT if i only send Data without Notification property, only foreground and background. Not when app closed. Im using a Xiaomi, autostart is on, battery restriction off.

Comment: You can try to test if this problem occurs on other devices.